# How to filter a dataset using a parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have two reports which share one stored procedure as a dataset source and are almost identical except of filter clausule.
I've created an inner report parameter and what to set a filter according to this param.

I've tried:

```
...data
    WHERE 
        CASE WHEN @ReportFilter = 1 THEN apd.[Date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
             WHEN @ReportFilter = 2 THEN pd.[Date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
        END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use your case expression to return a single date value and then check if that value is between @DateFrom and @DateTo. I also simplified the case expression a bit.

```
WHERE 
    CASE @ReportFilter 
        WHEN 1 THEN apd.[Date]
        WHEN 2 THEN pd.[Date] 
    END
    BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
```

But be careful with BETWEEN, it can cause some challenges:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(1 = CASE WHEN @ReportFilter = 1 and apd.[Date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo then 1
          WHEN @ReportFilter = 2 and pd.[Date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo then 1
        END)
```

Comment: It was accepted by Management Studio, but why's there "(1=CASE..." and "then 1"?

Comment: You need to check apd.[Date] BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo when reportfilter is equal to 1. Hence when both conditions are true then 1 will be evaluated with 1 (1=1) fulfilling your requirement.